# (SaltStack) ID dog in SLS dog is not a dictionary

Tags: salt-stack

I have been trying to find a pattern (bcm2708_wdog) in the /etc/modules file and if it isnt there add it to the bottom.  Every time I try this I get the "ID dog in SLS dog is not a dictionary".  I have no idea what this means.
Here is the file:

```
dog:
  - file.replace:
    - name: /etc/modules
    - pattern: 'bcm2708_wdog'
    - append_if_not_found: True
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It should probably look like this:

```
dog:
  file.replace:    # <--------this line was your problem.
    - name: /etc/modules
    - pattern: 'bcm2708_wdog'
    - append_if_not_found: True
```

Lines beginning with "-" denote items in a list. In your version, you've defined the top-level "dog" element as a list containing a dictionary. Salt expects it to be a straight dictionary instead, hence the error.

Comment: Thank you so much, now I know how to use "-" properly!  I just started working with salt so thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your version, in 2018

You will get that message if wrote the state with just 'file.replace' without the "dog" on top.

file.replace:
    - name: /etc/modules
    - pattern: 'bcm2708_wdog'
    - append_if_not_found: True