# Salt grains in Jinja template

Tags: jinja2, salt-stack

I am trying to do something simple in SaltStack: manage the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file using a formula. Here's the relevant section in my `formula/init.sls` file:

```
/etc/apt/sources.list:
  - file.managed:
    - template: jinja
    - source: salt://pkg/files/etc/apt/sources.list
    - user: root
    - group: root
    - mode: 0644

refresh-apt:
  cmd.wait:
    - name: '/usr/bin/apt-get -y update'
    - watch:
      - file: /etc/apt/sources.list
```

And here's the file `pkg/files/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
{{ pillar['headers']['salt']['file'] }}

deb http://{{ grains['aws_package_zone'] }}.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ {{ grains['oscodename'] }} main universe multiverse
deb-src http://{{ grains['aws_package_zone'] }}.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ {{ grains['oscodename'] }} main universe multiverse

deb http://{{ grains['aws_package_zone'] }}.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ {{ grains['oscodename'] }}-updates main universe multiverse
deb-src http://{{ grains['aws_package_zone'] }}.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ {{ grains['oscodename'] }}-updates main universe multiverse

deb http://{{ grains['aws_package_zone'] }}.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ {{ grains['oscodename'] }}-backports main universe multiverse
deb-src http://{{ grains['aws_package_zone'] }}.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ {{ grains['oscodename'] }}-backports main universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu {{ grains['oscodename'] }}-security main universe multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu {{ grains['oscodename'] }}-security main universe multiverse
```

The `grains['aws_package_zone']` returns the string `us-west-2` in this case (or whatever code for the zone you're in) and `grains['oscodename']` will return the name of the Ubuntu codename for that release: trusty, xenial,  etc.

Clearly Salt doesn't like this because when I try to run `state.highstate` I get the following error:

```
machine.fqdn:
    Data failed to compile:
----------
    ID /etc/apt/sources.list in SLS pkg is not a dictionary
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong...any suggestions? Sorry if this is basic.

Comment: This question is a duplicate of [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31414095/4638839); you can find your answer there. Also, rather than templating sources.list, you may want to look into the [pkgrepo.managed](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.pkgrepo.html) state.

Comment: (note that the actual problem is nothing to do with the grains access in jinja; that looks correct to me)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Andrew mentioned in his comment, the problem is with the extra '-' in the `/etc/apt/sources.list` definition:

```
...
/etc/apt/sources.list:
  - file.managed: <<-- remove this dash; should be just 'file.managed'
    - template: jinja
...
```